# What happens if I cancel contract deployment midway through?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I would love if someone could clarify what occurs if you cancel a migration midway through, I'm hoping that no harm is done and my artifacts still point to the right corrects.

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
... 0x1453fbfb5c9fbeb5eb29097b0298c4e1dd36cf3e49e42e7e72205e42df8a0877
```

This is where I pressed the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that point the only the contract deployment is active, so nothing should occur, however you can easily double check using a block explorer such as etherscan.